# Feeds importing unique nodes over and over

Tags: 7, feeds

I'm trying to import events to a calendar from an external ics..
I installed the Calendar module with the Feeds module. Unfortunately it creates the whole time new nodes. Even if the UID is unique (mapped to field field_gimme_uid) in the node. Update nodes is setted 'on'. I have checked everything but everything seems alright. The unique field is correctly imported (and the same for multiple nodes)..

I have a **contenttype "Evenement"** with the following fields:

- Evenement (title)
- Datum (field_event_date) Date
- Gimme-UID (field_gimme_uid) Text

I have a **feed** that maps the ics import to the nodes

```
$feeds_importer = new stdClass();
$feeds_importer->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default feeds_importer disabled initially */
$feeds_importer->api_version = 1;
$feeds_importer->id = 'ics_importer';
$feeds_importer->config = array(
  'name' => 'Gimme Agenda',
  'description' => 'Gimme agenda importeren van het account website',
  'fetcher' => array(
    'plugin_key' => 'FeedsHTTPFetcher',
    'config' => array(
      'auto_detect_feeds' => 0,
      'use_pubsubhubbub' => 0,
      'designated_hub' => '',
      'request_timeout' => '',
      'auto_scheme' => '',
      'accept_invalid_cert' => 0,
      'cache_http_result' => 1,
    ),
  ),
  'parser' => array(
    'plugin_key' => 'DateiCalFeedsParser',
    'config' => array(
      'indefinite_count' => '52',
      'indefinite_message_display' => TRUE,
      'until_not_utc' => FALSE,
      'skip_days' => NULL,
    ),
  ),
  'processor' => array(
    'plugin_key' => 'FeedsNodeProcessor',
    'config' => array(
      'expire' => '-1',
      'author' => '1',
      'authorize' => 1,
      'mappings' => array(
        0 => array(
          'source' => 'SUMMARY',
          'target' => 'title',
          'unique' => 0,
          'language' => 'und',
        ),
        1 => array(
          'source' => 'DTSTART',
          'target' => 'field_event_date:start',
          'unique' => FALSE,
          'language' => 'und',
        ),
        2 => array(
          'source' => 'DTEND',
          'target' => 'field_event_date:end',
          'unique' => FALSE,
          'language' => 'und',
        ),
        3 => array(
          'source' => 'UID',
          'target' => 'field_gimme_uid',
          'unique' => TRUE,
          'language' => 'und',
        ),
      ),
      'insert_new' => '1',
      'update_existing' => '1',
      'update_non_existent' => 'skip',
      'input_format' => 'plain_text',
      'skip_hash_check' => 0,
      'bundle' => 'evenement',
      'language' => 'und',
    ),
  ),
  'content_type' => '',
  'update' => 0,
  'import_period' => '900',
  'expire_period' => 3600,
  'import_on_create' => 1,
  'process_in_background' => 1,
);
```

**My modules**:

- Drupal 7.56
- Calendar module 7.x-3.5
- Date 7.x-2.10
- Date iCal 7.x-3.9
- Feeds 7.x-2.0-beta4

**My ICS** that I use to import can you find [here](https://api.gimme.eu/YEh46JUGQjlYrSSweownuQZqcFvlRy3jjrV7yDhppSG/icsevents/user.ics)

**Why is it importing the whole time the same nodes?**

Answer (score 0):

My bad! The **"Unique" option** in the feeds module isn't working without the **module "Field Validation"**. I added an unique rule to the contenttype "evenement" and now it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

The "Unique" option in the feeds module is working out-of-the-box only with title field.
If you're using another field - you need "field validation" module